# Kotlin type generic declaration

Tags: kotlin, generics

Suppose I have the following class

```java
public class Model<T extends Model> {}
```

I can declare in java as something like:

```java
Map<Class<? extends Model<?>>, String> lookup = new HashMap<>();
```

Question: how to declare the same typed variable (or field) in Kotlin?

Comment: `val lookup: MutableMap<Class<out Model<*>>, String> = HashMap()`

Comment: thanks @IR42, can you please answer the question so I can give you credential if it is accepted?